# Budget app problems

Tags: java, android

I want to create an app that where the main page will display the current balance and allow you to go to 1 of two pages. 
The second page will allow you to enter deposits.
The third page will allow you to make withdrawals.

I'm having a problem with the code, when I click the buttons on the main page, the page opened is blank. What am I doing wrong possibly that the page isn't showing?

Also, how can I carry the data from deposit or withdrawal pages over the main page to show the current balance?

Comment: Maybe the setContentView() is not used in your code. Or you have not delcare your activity in the Manifest

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are calling a new activity which is fine..

But you are not adding `setContentView(your layout)`... in `onCreate()` of new activity

That might be the reason you get blank screen...